# SeekBar not working while used in pop up window java android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar, android-popupwindow

Hi I've been trying to make a pop up window which presents a trackable seekbar as a part of a school project, both parts of the code work alone but when put together the seekbar progress is not tracked (you can move the seekbar but the number won't change), Help would be very appreciated!

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {

        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up, null);

        // create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = 500;
        boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window token
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

        // dismiss the popup window when touched
        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onButtonShowPopupWindowClick"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.368" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

popUp.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class popUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText("" + progress + "$");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

activity_pop_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="confirm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01999998" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:progress="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.78"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01999998" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="amount:"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.110000014" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="214dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.110000014" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if this caused the issue, but you need to replace `setContentView(R.alyout.activity_main)` in **PopUp activity** to `setContentView(R.alyout.activity_pop_up)`

Comment: hi, thanks for responding but this didn't fix the issue.